# How to handle intent for app built with Expo (Managed Workflow)?

Tags: react-native, expo, google-oauth, deep-linking

I’m trying to implement Google OAuth and want the user to be redirected back to the app with the access token received from Google after selecting an account. Right now, my google prompt changes to an infinite loading screen with the message “One Moment Please” after the account is selected.

This is the error message when I try to use Linking.openUrl(Linking.createURL()) for testing purposes:

```
Error message: 
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 3):
Error: Could not open URL<my_scheme>://': No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=<my_scheme>:///... flg=0x10000000 }
```

From what I’ve read, the solution is to use Deep Linking, so I added the following with no success.

```
// app.js

import * as Linking from "expo-linking";

export default function App() {
    Linking.addEventListener("url", (url) => console.log(url));

    return (<MyApp/>)
}
```

Here is some info that might be of help:

expo workflow: managed

Expo SDK: 48

Linking.createURL() returns “<my_scheme>://”

```
// app.json

“expo”: {
    “scheme”: <package_name received from Google Cloud Console>
}
```